# How do i load images that are not in the working directory?

Tags: python

Im trying to program chess in python using pygame but i cant load images from a diferent directory,
here's the code.

```
king=pygame.image.load(os.path.basename(r"C:\Users\tiago\PycharmProjects\chess\pieces\w_king.png"))
pos = [4, 0]
coords = translate_coord(pos)
display.blit(king, coords)
pygame.display.flip()
```

i keep getting the "FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory." error and i don know whats wrong.

Comment: Just `king=pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\tiago\PycharmProjects\chess\pieces\w_king.png")` (without `basename()`)

Comment: ... [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) returns the base name of pathname path. (e.g. `basename` for '/foo/bar/' returns 'bar')

Comment: next time first use `print()` to see what path you created.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the file path string to `pygame.image.load` without using `os.path.basename`. Also, you can pass a relative path instead, and if you want to make the file path cross platform, you can call `os.path.join()` like this, assuming the current working directory is `C:\Users\tiago\PycharmProjects\chess`:

```
king = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("pieces", "w_king.png"))
```

The issue with what you have is that `os.path.basename` is returning `w_king.png`, but assuming your current working directory is `C:\Users\tiago\PycharmProjects\chess`, pygame cannot find the file because what it actually needs to find is `pieces\w_king.png`, hence why in my solution above I have `os.path.join("pieces", "w_king.png"))`, which would return `pieces\w_king.png` on your system.

**Edit:**

As mentioned by @Rabbid76 you should make sure that the current working directory is the same directory as the source file before the code to load the image, if you are passing a relative path, like so:

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
king = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("pieces", "w_king.png"))
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, that's a good point, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `os.path.basename` This returns `w_king.png` in your case.

It looks like `pygame.image.load` requires a file type object. You can obtain this using `open()`

```
with open(r"C:\Users\tiago\PycharmProjects\chess\pieces\w_king.png") as filehandle:
    king=pygame.image.load(filehandle)

# do stuff with king
pos = [4, 0]
coords = translate_coord(pos)
display.blit(king, coords)
pygame.display.flip()
```

Edit: Never mind, looks like `pygame.image.load` can also handle a file path string although I believe my answer also works.

Comment: [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) accepts a file  path. You can pass the filename directly  to the function. Your answer overcomplicates the code.

Comment: Suspect, if the difference is that important?

Comment: Its not assumptions. `Load an image from a file source. You can pass either a filename or a Python file-like object.`

Comment: So remove the sentence *"I believe my answer also works."*. Anyway, you need 2 lines of code for something that can be done by calling a function with 1 argument.